# How to get full image url with python

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I have some problem with parsing links for images (images of house) on this site (https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/trekhkomnatnaya-kvartira-v-blagoustroennom-i-spokoynom-kurortnom-poselke-o26252)

How can i get full link?
How can I get data from src (in all images) and combine it into full link with site domain?

Im try it but cant get full link because dont kbow how to take link in src

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/neveroyatnaya-kvartira-s-vidom-na-more-tip-pentkhaus-o26253')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

urls = root.select('#slider > li > img[src]')
print(urls)
# [<img alt="" src="/photos/5e2c79b4-7da2-478e-a783-ad8f010d0b15.jpg"/>, , <img alt="" src="/photos/90f58624-1f32-46a2-afc9-ad8f010e2703.jpg"/>]
```

Comment: Do you want the image URLs shown in slider? Can you use `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: Show what you already tried.

Comment: Let me know if you are looking for solution using Selenium ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you could get that far and not know how to get the `src` attribute:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = 'https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/neveroyatnaya-kvartira-s-vidom-na-more-tip-pentkhaus-o26253'

rs = requests.get(base)
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

urls = root.select('#slider > li > img[src]')
for url in urls:
    print( base+url['src'] )
```